# Installing LuaFileSystem

Tags: dll, windows-7, lua, installation, visual-studio-2013

Long story short, I am installing LuaFileSystem to install opengl loader gen. However, I can not install LuaFileSystem, because it keeps producing this error:

```
C:\Users\username\Downloads\luafilesystem-master\luafilesystem-master>luarocks in
stall luafilesystem
Installing http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/luafilesystem-1.6.2-2.src.rock
...

7-Zip 9.10 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-12-22

Processing archive: luafilesystem-1.6.2.tar.gz

Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2.tar

Everything is Ok

Size:       122880
Compressed: 27886

7-Zip 9.10 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-12-22

Processing archive: luafilesystem-1.6.2.tar

Extracting  pax_global_header
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\Makefile
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\Makefile.win
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\README
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\config
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\config.win
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us\examples.html
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us\index.html
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us\license.html
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us\luafilesystem.png
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us\manual.html
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.3.0-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.4.0-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.4.0-2.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.4.1-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.4.1rc1-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.4.2-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.5.0-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.6.0-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.6.1-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.6.2-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-cvs-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-cvs-2.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\src
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\src\.gitignore
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\src\lfs.c
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\src\lfs.def
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\src\lfs.h
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\tests
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\tests\test.lua
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\vc6
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\vc6\lfs.def
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\vc6\luafilesystem.dsw
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\vc6\luafilesystem_dll.dsp

Everything is Ok

Folders: 7
Files: 31
Size:       86449
Compressed: 122880
cl /MD /O2 -c -Fosrc/lfs.obj -IC:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/include src/lfs.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

lfs.c
c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_luafilesystem-1.6.2-2-357\luafilesy
stem-1.6.2\src\lfs.c(413) : warning C4716: 'make_link' : must return a value
link -dll -def:lfs.def -out:lfs.dll C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lib/lua5.1.li
b src/lfs.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Creating library lfs.lib and object lfs.exp

Error: Build error: Failed installing lfs.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\
rocks/luafilesystem/1.6.2-2/lib

C:\Users\username\Downloads\luafilesystem-master\luafilesystem-master>
```

Environment Detail:
 Windows 7 64 Bit, Visual Studio 13

Do I need to run it as adminstrator? If so, I do not know how to run this script as adminstrator.

Comment: hmmm... `Win + R` -> `cmd` -> `Shift + Ctrl + Enter` should get You to terminal as Administrator.

Comment: thank you, I believe that did the trick, i just can not install opengl loader still ... but filesystem works

Comment: current version of LFS has bug on Win x64 I have problem on Win 8 x64 with MSVC (i do not test it on mingw). See https://github.com/keplerproject/luafilesystem/issues/26. May be you should use scm version.

Comment: When I run it as adminstrator and did the process again, I got a different error, it says the file already existed. I did downloaded the one that says lua for windows, so I am not sure if it was included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, Windows does not recognize such an installation cases and do not prompt anything *automagically*. So, You **must** install it as Administrator.

One of the ways to get to  Windows terminal as Admin:
`Win + R` -> `cmd` -> `Shift + Ctrl + Enter`.